# Wrong time for same timezone in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I am passing param of type XML as a stored procedure param succesfully. I have no problems handling all the data from XML, but I discovered that dates from XML are not retrieved properly.

For example, `2013-03-14T15:14:53.598438+01:00` is now `2013-03-14 14:14:00`. It seems that SQL is calculating `+1` to display time.

I am using following T-SQL to get date from xml

```
select 
   A.B.value('xs:dateTime((ConfirmationDate)[1])', 'smalldatetime') as ConfirmationDate
FROM    
   @XML.nodes('/ArrayOfPreOrder/PreOrder/confirmationinfo/ConfirmationInfo') A(B)) as ConfirmationDate
```

How can I correct this issue? Both server and SQL Server are in the same timezone.

Comment: Do both have the same DST behaviour? Is DST set up correctly on both servers?

Comment: Have you actually checked the behaviour and definition on the servers, or are you assuming that the servers are properly set up because they are in the samae time zone. I have encountered an astounding number of DA's over the years who had no knowledge or understanding of how to properly set up TZ on thier machines.

Comment: I have checked it, but would also like to hear you suggestion how to check TZ on server machine.

Comment: Try `SELECT SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()`

Answer (score 1):

Check if there is a difference between your timezone setting and the timezone you're importing...

```
SELECT SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()

DECLARE @TimeZone NVARCHAR(255)
EXEC master.dbo.xp_instance_regread 

N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', 
N'SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation',
N'TimeZoneKeyName',
@TimeZone OUTPUT

SELECT @TimeZone
```

You're specifying the timezone in the XML you're importing so I'm guessing it is converting it to local time for you. So your timezone would be +2 where you're importing from +1.

Comment: i think SELECT SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() is available only from sql 2008

Comment: Ah, what operating system do you have SQL Server installed on?

Comment: Try this `Select DateDiff(hh,GetUTCDate(),GetDate())`.